# How to delete element next to the highest found element in the circular list in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, linked-list, circular-list

I've got a problem with some function/algorithm, and I hope you guys can help me. The task is to write a function that will delete an element that is right after the hightest element(highest value) in single linked circular list. I've been trying to draw this so this would make more sense to me, but it still looks like dark arts, but i've managed to come up with a function like this:

```
struct node
{
 node * next;
 double data;
};

 void Insert_node(node * & head, double v)
 {
  node * p = new node;

  p->data = v;
  if(head)
  {
   p->next = head->next;
   head->next = p;
  }
  else p->next = p;
  head = p;
  }


void Delete_After_Max(node* & head)
{
   node * tmp=head;
   int counter=0,index=0;
   double maximum=0;

 if(tmp) // checking if the list is not empty
 {
    do
    {
      if(tmp->data>maximum)
      {
          maximum=tmp->data;
          index=counter+1;
      }
    counter++;
    tmp=tmp->next;
  } while(tmp!=head);
}

cout<<"Biggest value on the list: "<<maximum<<endl;
cout<<"licznik:"<<counter<<"  "<<"indeks: "<<index<<endl;

if(counter==(index+1))
   index=0;    //if last element is the maximum, first one will be deleted
 else
   index++; // incrementing to get index of the next element after maximum

node *tmp2=NULL;
//checking if the highest element was last(then we delete first one)
if(index==0)
    {
    index=counter;
    }
// checking if the highest element was somewhere else

node *tmp3=NULL;

int position=0;

if((index>0)&& (index<=counter))
   {
       tmp2=head;

       while(position<index-1)
        {
            tmp2=tmp2->next;
            position++;
        }

    tmp3=tmp2->next;
    tmp2->next=tmp3->next;

    if(head==tmp3)
    {
        head=head->next;
    }
    delete tmp3;

   }
 }
```

Do you think this algorithm is right? I'm not sure if I get the idea right, so the code is probably totally wrong :/

At first, I count all the elements on the list, find the highest one and it's index, and then I can use it to delete element after that by incrementing the index, right? I think that it's ok to this moment, but after that it gets harder to me, if the maximum was last element, i have to delete the first one, and "connect" the last one with the second one? But I don't know if it's ok with circular list, so please, can someone give me a hint what I'am doing wrong? ;)

I checked it again, and it compiles but it's not working properly, and I still don't know why, and how to do it. I couldn't find any similar problems that I could base on, any kind of help would be appreciated, I'am new to this, that's why there are so many mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

In the proposed algorithm, small errors are doing a wrong result.

**Error 1** - the biggest, in the last while-loop the `tmp2` is not initialized.

> Initialize `tmp2 = head` instead of `tmp3 = head;`.

```
tmp2 = head; // initialize tmp2
while (position<index - 1)
{
    tmp2 = tmp2->next;
    position++;
}
tmp3 = tmp2->next;
```

**Error 2** - starting with `position` equal 1 will stop the loop too early.

> Using first `position = 1` with the while-condition `(position < index
>   - 1)` decrease the loop by 2 steps.

```
int position = 0;
```

**Typo Error** - in the `if (index == 0)` condition, a missing semi-column.

> The line code `head = head->next` doesn't end by `;`.

In the condition `if (index == 0)` either exiting from the function with `return` or prevent doing unexpected operation by inserting the last part in a `else { ...  }` condition.

```
if (index == 0)
{
    tmp2 = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete tmp2;
    // EXIT by return
}
```

**ADDED N°1>>>>**

**Error 3** - the case `if (index == 0)` is not possible

> Try to delete the first node of the circular linked-list when the
>   maximum is placed in the last node is not possible.

- The value `index = 0;` is possible only when `if (counter == index)`. But in the do-while, just after storing the position of the maximum in `index = counter;` the `counter` is incremented `counter++;`.

Modify as follow:

```
if (counter == (index+1)) // detecting the last position
    index = 0;    //if last element is the maximum, first one will be deleted
else
    index++; // incrementing to get index of the next element after maximum
```

- But to delete the first node, the proposed algorithm for `if (index == 0)` doesn't work because it is necessary to store the previous node.

**Solution** - The best solution is to force the last while-loop to continue one step more by doing the following changes:

```
if (index == 0)
{
    index = counter;
}
```

Then allow the while-loop when `(index == counter)` with:

```
if ((index>0) && (index<=counter)) // allow for the last
{
    tmp2 = head;
    while (position<index - 1)
```

And before the deletion of the `tmp3` node, modify the `head` when `tmp3 == head`:

```
    tmp3 = tmp2->next;
    tmp2->next = tmp3->next;
    if (head==tmp3) { // when the node to delete is the head
        head = head->next; // shift head to the next node
    }
    delete tmp3;
```

**ADDED N°2>>>>**

**Output** - here is the obtain result when using the suggested list of values.

> The first element `6` is the deleted (next element of the last element
>   `18` in a circular linked-list).

```
[ 6, 9, 13, 12, 1, 10, 15, 4, 6, 18, ].
Biggest value on the list: 18
[ 9, 13, 12, 1, 10, 15, 4, 6, 18, ].
```

**ADDED N°3>>>>**

> Here is the full source code of the function `Delete_After_Max()`:

```
void Delete_After_Max(node* & head)
{
    node * tmp = head;
    int counter = 0, index = 0;
    double maximum = -1;

    if (tmp) // checking if the list is not empty
    {
        do
        {
            if (tmp->data>maximum)
            {
                maximum = tmp->data;
                index = counter;
            }
            counter++;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        } while (tmp != head);
    }

    std::cout << "Biggest value on the list: " << maximum << "\n";
    if (counter == (index+1))
        index = 0;    //if last element is the maximum, first one will be deleted
    else
        index++; // incrementing to get index of the next element after maximum

    node *tmp2 = NULL;
    //checking if the highest element was last(then we delete first one)
    if (index == 0)
    {
        tmp2 = head;
        std::cout << tmp2->data << ", ";
        index = counter;
        //head = head->next;
        //delete tmp2;
        // EXIT
    }
    // checking if the highest element was somewhere else

    node *tmp3 = NULL;

    int position = 0; // ERROR 1;

    // if ((index>0) && (index<counter))
    if ((index>0) && (index<=counter))
    {
        // ERROR tmp3 = head;
        tmp2 = head;
        while (position<index - 1)
        {
            tmp2 = tmp2->next;
            position++;
        }
        tmp3 = tmp2->next;
        tmp2->next = tmp3->next;
        if (head==tmp3) {
            head = head->next;
        }
        delete tmp3;
    }
}
```

**ADDED N°4>>>>**

In the updated function `Delete_After_Max()` displayed bellow the logical to delete the node following the maximum is wrong.

```
bool Delete_After_Max(node* & head)
{
    node *maxi=Find_Maximum(head);
    std::cout << "Biggest value on the list: " << maxi->data << "\n";

    if(!Is_Empty) // !Is_Empty because this function is not working properly so i had to negate it until i find out why ;)
    {
        cout<<"the list is empty";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        node *tmp3=NULL;
        node *tmp2=maxi->next;
        tmp3=tmp2->next;
        tmp2->next=tmp3->next;
        if (head==tmp3) {
            head = head->next;
        }
        delete tmp3;

        cout<<"one element deleted";

        return true;
    }
}
```

1. If `maxi` is pointing to the node having the maximum value, the node to be delete is `maxi->next` (instead of calling `tmp2` we will call it `node_to_delete`).
2. Before deleting the `node_to_delete`, it is necessary to connect the node `maxi` with the node following the `node_to_delete` (instead of calling `tmp3` we will call it `node_after_delete`).
3. In case of the `node_to_delete` is the `head`, it is necessary to update the `head` with its next node before deletion.

Then, the new deletion part of the function becomes:

```
// Step 1
node *node_to_delete = maxi->next;
// Step 2
node *node_after_delete = node_to_delete->next;
maxi->next = node_after_delete;
// Step 3
if (node_to_delete == head) {
    head = head->next;
}
delete node_to_delete;
```

So, logic errors in the function `Delete_After_Max()` are:

1. Bad connection between the node `maxi` and the node `node_after_delete` (`tmp3`) ==> `maxi->next=tmp3;` instead of `tmp2->next=tmp3->next;`,
2. Bad definition of the node `node_to_delete` (`tmp2`) ==> `if (head==tmp2)` and `delete tmp2;` instead of `if (head==tmp3)` and `delete tmp3;`

Comment: Ok, I fixed the errors that you pointed out, but when I'm trying to run the whole code, it breaks down.. but maybe there's a problem with other parts of the code, but now I only need this algorithm to be right ;).So the algorithm suppose to work properly now that I fixed the errors? or maybe I missed some case's and it still doesn't make any sense?

Comment: I worked on the code, but set position at 1, not 0 like you said, and it is working : the numer of elements decrease by 1 and the element after the biggest one is not displayed after I use this function, but there is one problem- if the highest value is at the last element, it breaks down, and I dont know how to solve this problem

Comment: @WojtekMika, to be sure that the function `Delete_After_Max()`, it is necessary to know how the data are added/inserted in your circular linked-list. Could you edit the question and add the `struct node` definition and the `insert()` function ? _Note: I have created my own simple `insert()` function, but not sure it matches with yours !!!_

Comment: I edited the comment, I think the insert function work properly, and the Delete function works almost properly, except this one situation where the highest element is the "last one" on the list, but I don't know how to work it out because it suppose to be circled list... If the last element is the highest one, the first one should be deleted, but it just doesn't work in my code

Comment: I have added the solution for the case _'the highest element is the "last one" on the list'_.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but it seems like this solution is not working when maximum is the last element, i made changes accordingly to your suggestions, but i keep having the same problem with the last element, it just cant disappear :/ I edited the comment with my code above, maybe i would ask my teacher where is the mistake, but maybe you would give me one last advice :p 
And I still dont know at what value should be variable position set at, because you wrote it should be 0, but it works only if its at 1

Comment: @WojtekMika, could you add a complete example with the tested series of data where the maximum is in the last position ? When using your insert function and `position=0`, it's work for me.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/cCyYf), im filling the list of 10 elements with random numbers, and as you see, in this case, after calling the delete function and display function it stays exactly the way it was, i will edit my code comment and put these functions after your suggestions
And, when i use position=0, it deletes not the first one after the maximum, but the second...

Comment: @WojtekMika, I have added the output based to your series of data. No problem to remove the next node when the maximum is the last node of the circular linked-list.

Comment: I see that you get good results, but I still don't know why my code is not working, I did all that you told me to do, maybe I missed something and I just can't see it, maybe you could send me your version of deleting function and i will compare it and catch the mistake by myself?

Comment: @WojtekMika just added the full source code of the function `Delete_After_Max()`.

Comment: thank you very much! i was thinking that maybe i would make it a bool type function, that will return false if the list was empty, and true if i was able to delete the element, and also im gonna try to write a function that will search for the maximum in the list and return a pointer to that element, but i hope im gonna be able to do this modifications by myself :) and once again, thank you for your kind help!

Comment: @WojtekMika, the algorithm could be simplified by storing the pointer of the node having the maximum value `maxi = tmp;` instead of storing an index `index = counter;` and performing a second while-loop to delete the next node.

Comment: yes, this way it would be much simpler, especially for me to understand it, I wrote a functions that finds the maximum and returns a pointer to it, and also a function that checks if the list is empty or not(but it's not working somehow, and maybe it's because head is set at null somewhere and I dont see that? ). I also modified the Delete_After_Max function, and it's pretty simple right now, but once again, I dont know how to implement it to work in case where the last element is the maximum and i have to delete the first one, could you take a look?  http://pastebin.com/9rYUsxUF

Comment: @WojtekMika, just added details relative to the deletion part of the function `Delete_After_Max()`.

Comment: it works great now, so i created 3 cases: empty list-return false, 1 element-return false(already works), and >1 element-return true and delete the element after maximum(works). My final question(i hope so) will be- why isn't my Is_Empty function working? i want it to return true if list is empty, and it seems that my list is always empty, which is strange given the fact, that i fill it with values in for-loop... (that's why i have to negate it inside the Delete_After_Max function which is stupid

Comment: @WojtekMika, in the function `Delete_After_Max()` the call `if(!Is_Empty)` is wrong (you are testing if the function-pointer `Is_Empty` doesn't exists). You may call `if(Is_Empty(head))`.

Comment: God, you're right, im so dumb! Is there any way i can create an empty list? because when i comment the for-loop the program crashes, i just want to test the situation when the list is really empty and i don't know why, basically head is set at null but it's not working

Comment: @WojtekMika, using `node * head = NULL;` is the way to have an empty list. For the _"program crashes"_, the problem is localized in the function `Delete_After_Max()` when you are trying to display `maxi->data` and `maxi` is equal to `NULL`.

Comment: ok, so it's working perfect now, and is much simpler than my first idea! once again- big thank you! you should have a statue built for your patience! :)